# Legends not appearing in ggnet2 plot along with wrong color for edges

Tags: r, ggplot2, igraph

I need to create a network plot where the color of nodes and edges will be dependent on a parameter. Though I have been able to render the graph, the color of edges are not reflecting properly and the legend is also not appearing.
A similar question is already present in Stackoverflow at the below link:

[Color legend not appearing in ggnet2 plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320669/color-legend-not-appearing-in-ggnet2-plot)

Below is a reproducible code. Any help would be great

```
library(network)
library(sna)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnetwork)
library(sna)
library(GGally)



edge_df = data.frame("Start" = c(1,2,4,5), "End" = c(2,3,3,1), "strength" = 
c("uncovered","uncovered","covered","uncovered"))


vertex_df = data.frame("Nodes" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "strength" = 
c("covered","uncovered","uncovered",                                                                             
"uncovered","covered"))

net = network(edge_df[,1:2], directed = FALSE)


net %v% "nodes" = ifelse(vertex_df$strength == "covered", "Nodes Covered", 
"Nodes Uncovered")

net %v% "color_node" = ifelse(net %v% "nodes" == "Nodes Covered", 
"steelblue", "yellow")

net %e% "weight" = ifelse(edge_df$strength == "covered", "Edges Covered", 
"Edges Uncovered")

set.edge.attribute(net, "color", ifelse(net %e% "weight" == "Edges Covered", 
"green", "red"))


set.seed(123)
ggnet2(net, color = "color_node",
edge.color = "color", 
edge.size = 0.5,
node.size = 1,
mode = "fruchtermanreingold",
color.legend = c("timers","weight")) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
text = element_text(color = "white"),
legend.position = "bottom")
```